# how to currency convert in java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

1. how to convert currency in java-script like pound, dolor, and any
   currency please reply html designing html code
2. this is my html css and javascript code

```
<div class="fxborder"> <div
class="fxheader">Currency Converter</div> <form action=""> <p
class="fx">Amount:<br /> <input name="Amount" value="1"
maxlength="15" size="15" class="fx" /> <br />From:<br /> <select
name="RateFrom" class="fx"> <option class="fx"
value="0.3363">Argentine Peso</option> </select> <select
name="RateTo" class="fx"> <option class="fx"
value="0.3363">Argentine Peso</option> </select> </p> <p class="fx">
<input name="calc" value="Convert" type="button"
onclick="temp(this.form)" class="fxsubmit" /><br /> Result:<br />
<input name="Exchange" readonly="readonly" size="15"
class="fxresults" /> </p> </form> <p class="fx">&rarr;<a
href="http://www.timegenie.com/currency_converter" title="free
currency converter for your web site" class="fxlink">Free currency
converter</a><br /> &rarr;<a href="http://www.timegenie.com/"
title="world time and time zone converter" class="fxlink">Time zone
converter</a></p> </div>
```

Comment: You want to convert currencies. But the currency values are volatile and they alter very frequently. How will you get this information from? It might be some web service preferably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this guy right here: http://www.gocurrency.com/add-converter.htm

or this one :) http://cconv.textor.com/

Answer (score 0):

As currencies are volatile, We can not use constant mathematical formalae, you can try below currency converter javascript code  [Foreign exchange resource](http://www.foreignexchangeresource.com/converter-code.php)